# Square-root of a matrix which arise from truncating a matrix which has a square-root

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I have this covariance matrix $A$ which has a symmetric Toeplitz structure.

\begin{equation}
A = \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccc}
c_0 & c_1 & c_2 & \cdots & c_{n-1} & c_{n} \\
c_1 & c_0 & c_1 & \cdots & c_{n-2} & c_{n-1} \\
c_2 & c_1 & c_0 & \cdots & c_{n-3} & c_{n-2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
c_{n-1} & c_{n-2} & c_{n-3} & \cdots & c_0 & c_1 \\
c_{n} & c_{n-1} & c_{n-2} & \cdots & c_1 & c_0 \end{array} \right]
\end{equation}

$A$ can be embedded in a larger circulant matrix $C$, as indicated below by the lines inside the matrix. For the first row of $C$ the appending uses the $n-1$ middle elements of the first row of $A$, in reverse order. The next row of $C$ is a right shifted version of the first row where the element which is moved outside the matrix ($c_1$) is moved to the first position. The following rows are found by the same procedure.

\begin{equation}
C = \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
c_0 & c_1       & \cdots & c_{n-1} & c_{n} \;\;\;|                  & c_{n-1} & \cdots & c_1 \\
c_1                      & c_0       & \cdots & c_{n-2} & c_{n-1} |                & c_{n}   & \cdots & c_2 \\
  \vdots                 &  \vdots   &        &           &  \vdots\;\;\;\;\;\;|                   &           &        & \vdots \\
c_{n}                  & c_{n-1} & \cdots & c_1       & c_0\;\;\;\;| & c_1       & \cdots & c_{n-1} \\
-- & -- & -- & -- & -- & & &\\
    \vdots               &    \vdots &        &           & \vdots                    &           &        & \vdots \\
c_1                      & c_2       & \cdots & c_{n}   & c_{n-1}                 & c_{n-2} & \cdots & c_0
\end{array} \right]
\end{equation}

$C$ can be diagonalized by use of the Fourier matrix, i.e. $C = F^H D F$. Its eigenvalues $D$ can be found by a Fourier transformation of its first column. The square-root of $C$ is given by $C^{1/2} = F^H D^{1/2} F$.

By use of a special form of zero-padding $ZP$ and "reverse" zero-padding $RZP$ one can compute,
\begin{equation}
A^{1/2} u = RZP( C^{1/2} ZP(u)) = RZP( IFFT( D^{1/2} FFT( ZP(u)))),
\end{equation}
where $u$ is an arbitrary vector. This is computationally very efficient.

I now want to make all sample points uncorrelated to the i'th sample point. That corresponds to removing the i'th row and column of $A$ or set that row and column to zero (except point (i,i)). Lets call this modified/truncated version of $A$ for $B$. Its here illustrated for the second row/column:

\begin{equation}
B = \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccc}
c_0 & 0 & c_2 & \cdots & c_{n-1} & c_{n} \\
0   & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
c_2 & 0 & c_0 & \cdots & c_{n-3} & c_{n-2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
c_{n-1} & 0 & c_{n-3} & \cdots & c_0 & c_1 \\
c_{n} & 0 & c_{n-2} & \cdots & c_1 & c_0 \end{array} \right] \text{ or }
\left[ \begin{array}{ccccccc}
c_0  & c_2 & \cdots & c_{n-1} & c_{n} \\
c_2  & c_0 & \cdots & c_{n-3} & c_{n-2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots \\
c_{n-1} & c_{n-3} & \cdots & c_0 & c_1 \\
c_{n} & c_{n-2} & \cdots & c_1 & c_0 \end{array} \right]
\end{equation}

**My question is: Can the square-root of $B$ be calculated on basis of $C$?**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think that if you want someone to read all this you should put a bounty on the question

Comment: @Dac0 You are so right. Therefore I have tried to reduce and modify the text and add illustrations of the matrices.